# Trying to write from pseudocode in c++ (divide_recursive algorithm)

Tags: c++, algorithm, pseudocode

i'm having issues finding this bug on my code, i think it's in the use of array as return data type in the algorithm. I used arrays because c++ doesn't return 2 variables like it's on the pseudocode.
The algorithm takes in input 2 integers x and y, and in out gives 2 integers q,r (i use an array a[] of 2 elements) with the quotient and reminders.

pseudocode:

```
divide(x,y)
    if x = 0: return (q,r) <-- (0,0)
    (q,r) <-- divide(x/2,y)
    q = 2*q, r= 2*r
    if x is odd: r= r+1
    if r>=y: r=r-y, q = q+1
    return(q,r)
```

c++ code:

```
    int  divisione(int x, int y)
    {
      int a[1];
        if(x == 0)
        {
            a[0] = 0;
            a[1] = 0;
            return *a;
        }
        int b[1];
        *b = divisione(x/2,y);
        a[0] = b[0]*2;
        a[1] = b[1]*2;
        if((x%2) != 0)
            a[1] = a[1]+1;
        if(a[1]>= y)
        {
            a[0]+=1;
            a[1]-=y;
        }
        return *a;
    }
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a request for others to do OP's work.

Comment: Q: how many elements do you think `int a[1];` has ?

Comment: ehr, i'm just trying to convert from pseudocode to c++ code a basic function found on my algorithms and data structures book, it's not something i'm going to pay for o getting any extra credit.

Comment: @paulR 2, right ? It should be my Quotient (q) and my reminder(r)

Comment: @blackdev1l _2, right ?_ No! That's a blatantly wrong assumption, `int a[1];` contains exactly **one** element of course. Indces start at `0` in c++, so accessing `a[1]` is out of range!!

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ you are absolutely right. I don't know why i write a[1].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two big problems with your code:

1. Your array `a` is declared with a size of 1, not 2, so when you access `a[1]`, you're accessing an element that doesn't exist, which is undefined behavior.
2. You are only returning the first element of your array.  That's what `*a` means.

Instead of using an array, just define a structure that matches your pseudocode.

```
typedef struct {
    int q;
    int r;
} DivisionResult;

DivisionResult division(int x, int y) {
    DivisionResult result;
    if (x == 0) {
        result.q = result.r = 0;
        return result;
    }

    result = division(x/2, y);
    result.q = result.q * 2;
    result.r = result.r * 2;
    if (x % 2 != 0) {
        result.r = result.r + 1;
    }
    if (result.r >= y) {
        result.q = result.q + 1;
        result.r = result.r - y;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: 1) Oh my god i'm so stupid.

2) Yes i know, it should return the pointer of the first element (q) and so where it's located q and r  (a[0] and a[1])

Comment: You cannot “return the pointer where it's located”.  That pointer becomes invalid when the function returns, because it points to an array on the stack, and stack variables cease to exist when the function returns.  See my revised answer.

Comment: Yes i think this is the best way to pass from this pseudocode to c++ code, basically when i will found again an algorithm with 2 return the best way is to use a class/struct ? Thank you so much anyway.

Answer (score 0):

As with 2 args to return, try passing those variable into divide [by Reference](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/73-passing-arguments-by-reference/).

I recommend writing a function with a signature more like

```
void divide(double num1, double num2, double &quotient, double &remainder)
{
    //check args
    remainder = num1 % num2;
    quotient = num1 / num2;
    //the above variables get returned since they were passed **by reference**
}
```

You could also make a small data structure to handle the result, as in:

```
struct DivideResult
{
    //these variables are public by default so you can do '*structname*.function'
    double quotient;
    double remainder;
}
```

Then you can just return one item, but I would still suggest the by ref solution.

Comment: I'm sure there are most efficient way to write a simple divide() function, i would to learn to pass from pseudocode found on my book to c++ code. WIth this kind of solution it's a different algorithm doing the same thing :)